# One slot keeps failing in a RAID-6 array, before and after RAID card swap: does the backplane have to be replaced?

Tags: raid, hardware-failure, repair

We have a 12 drive Supermicro 12U server SYS-6029P- WTRT with X11DDW-NT motherboard that was upgraded to a 7332895-LSI-MR-9361-16i RAID card so it could go from 8 to 12 SAS disks.

The drive in slot 3 had failed before RAID card upgrade.  But then it failed again after the new card was installed.   And the 2nd replacement drive failed too.  The error is "Other Error Count" according to storecli64 utility.  No other slot had these errors.  There were no "Media" errors.  The RAID drive eventually rebuilt, with 398 "Other" errors.

We suspected a bad cable, but a swap of the cable for slots 0-3 did not make the errors stop.

The remaining culprit is the backplane.

Has anyone ever seen a failed backplane in just one slot?  Is there a chance something has to be reseated or tightened, or is it probably a bad chip/capacitor?  What electronics does the backplane have?

Is replacing the backplane difficult?  The person who looked at it said it looked like a major undertaking (remove motherboard, disassemble), which would have to happen inside the datacenter by the rack.

The final possibility is to downgrade the array to 11 drives.

---

edit - the drive failed with ErrCd=46, ErrMsg="--".  Does anyone know how to parse this storecli64 error code?

Comment: Does the drive continue to get errors if you swap it into another slot?  Check the backplane slot for dirt in the slot.  Check that the slot has good airflow (and the drive isn't being cooked).  Some drives have built in temperature sensors that could help with that. (smartctl can read them)

Comment: I can't swap into another slot (the RAID is in use), but they seem to work on other machines, except for one, and that was not tested exhaustively.

Comment: Is it under warranty?  have you called supermicro for support?

Comment: It's no longer under warranty.    It's also a reseller's supermicro (so reseller had support obligations), and the reseller came under new ownership,   They've still helped with other stuff, but I think I'm on my own on this one.